# percentage format in Kartik GridView (yii2)

Tags: yii, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii2-basic-app

I am doing a project how to calculate total in yii2. When i'm building the project, i found trouble when i'm input data to be percent format. When I'm save data,in index look 2,300%, even though it is 23%. What can i do?
In my view, format like this'format'=>['percent',],

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvvpu.png)
this is my code

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel backend\models\LaporanSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Laporans';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="laporan-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Laporan', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'showPageSummary'=>true,

        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

           // 'id',
           // 'inv_no',
           // 'inv_date',
            //'rate',
             [
            'attribute'=>'kode_customer',
           // 'width'=>'150px',
            //'hAlign'=>'right',
          //  'format'=>['decimal', 0],
        ],
            // 'kode_item',
            // 'qty',
            // 'price',
            // 'ed',
             ['attribute'=>'total_price',
            'pageSummary'=>true
],
            // 'dsc',
['attribute'=>'total_dsc',
            'pageSummary'=>true
],            // 'trans',
['attribute'=>'total_trans',
            'pageSummary'=>true
],             
['attribute'=>'total_margin_rp',
            'pageSummary'=>true
],             
['attribute'=>'total_margin_persen',
            'pageSummary'=>true,
           // 'groupSeparator' => '.',
            'format'=>['percent',],



],            // 'kode_area',

            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: please  show me the real   total_margin_persen  value content of your db

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is probably due to the fact that you have stored the actual percentage value in the database. So for example your 23% is actually the number 23 in your database table.

If you look at the documentation for the percent formatter in Yii2 here (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asPercent()-detail) you will see that it says:

> The value to be formatted. It must be a factor e.g. 0.75 will result
>   in 75%.

So for your data to show up correctly you either have to provide the data as a factor, use a different formatter or write your own formatting function.